# Bluetooth is not working in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, bluetooth, vaio, sony

I have a Sony Vaio VPCEH35EN and yesterday I installed Ubuntu 12.10. Bluetooth is not working, can anyone help me please?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the output from the command "lsusb" so we can see what the hardware is.

Answer (score 0):

Try with installing :

```
sudo apt-get install bluez bluez-alsa bluez-audio bluez-btsco bluez-compat bluez-cups bluez-dbg bluez-gstreamer bluez-hcidump bluez-pcmcia-support bluez-tools bluez-utils python-bluez
```